# Exception from within a Finally on a Try-Finally block

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, try-catch-finally

What happens when a Exception is raised on a `Try-Finally` block (without `catch`) and another exception is raised on the `Finally` part?

Example:

```
Dim aux As String

Try
    Try
        aux.Split("."c)
    Finally
        aux = File.ReadAllText("")
    End Try
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex)
End Try
```

Comment: Generally, it is a bad idea to write code that even has a remote possibility of throwing an exception in the Catch or Finally sections.  Can create hard to debug errors.

Comment: @RobertBeaubien It has to be avoided, but to be sure is better to know what is going to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last thrown exception is catched.

In this case, the **ArgumentException** from `ReadAllText()` on the `Finally` block. Ignoring the first exception being thrown.